# my logical operator understanding attempt

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

status = False

while status == True:
    status == "retired"

def ageCheck():
    age = int(input("Enter Your Age: "))
    if ageCheck.age() >= 65 or age <18:
        status = True

def discountCheck():
    if (ageCheck.age() >= 65 and status == "retired") or ageCheck.age() < 18: 
        print("You get 5% off")

def welcome():
    print()
    print("Welcome to Age Test")


welcome()

ageCheck()

discountCheck()
```

i'm actually just attempting to build a program for understanding the logical operators. The issue is that it keeps throwing this error.

```
"File "/home/pi/Murach/randomtests/while test.py", line 10, in ageCheck
    if ageCheck.age() >= 65 or age <18:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'age'"
```

Comment: So... what's `ageCheck.age()` supposed to be?

Comment: Just use `age`. You are defining a function, not an object.

Comment: agecheck is a function - you access its "age()" attribute, which it has none. Hence the error. Use  `age` instead. Beware of scoping - the `status` inside ageCheck() is not your global status but a local variable. You use `status` as string or bool - depending on your functions. Decide wich one and use 2 different variables for status (as true/false) and status (as retired or not) .,,

Comment: agecheck is my attempt to understand how the Status == "retired" would work in a program. (if (ageCheck.age() >= 65 and status == "retired") or ageCheck.age() < 18: ) i'm trying to work this equation into a working program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`agecheck` is a function - you access its `age()` attribute, which it has none - hence the error.

Use `age` instead.

Beware of scoping - the `status` inside `ageCheck()` is not your global `status` but a local variable. You use `status` as `string` or `bool` - depending on your functions.

Decide which one or use 2 different variables for status (as true/false) and status (as retired or not).

You can rewrite some of your code like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def getAge():
    while True:
        age = input("Enter Your Age: ")

        if age.isdigit() and int(age) > 0: 
            return int(age)
        # repeat until number given

def isElegibleForDiscount(someAge, isRetired):
    return someAge < 18 or someAge >= 65 and isRetired # operator  precedence, no () needed 

def discountCheck(myAge,myStatus):
    if isElegibleForDiscount(myAge, myStatus == "retired"):
        print("You get 5% off")
    else:
        print("No discount, sorry.")

def welcome():
    print()
    print("Welcome to Age Test")


welcome()
age = getAge()
discountCheck(age,"retired")
discountCheck(age,"still kickin")
```

to avoid errors when parsing non-integer inputs, passing variables around without need of global variables and to facilitate your logic checks.

Output for 17:

```
Welcome to Age Test
Enter Your Age: 17
You get 5% off
You get 5% off
```

Output for 65:

```
Welcome to Age Test
Enter Your Age: 65
You get 5% off
No discount, sorry.
```

HTH

Comment: why exactly was there two discountCheck? (o-o)

Comment: @HectorAgosto  to showcase the difference between `retired` and `still kicking`

Comment: wow. i kept reading it until it made sense. Thank you for helping i understand code a bit better now !! :DD You were a great help. Though, for the two discount check, is it that "still kickin" returns true because there's no check for that ? i see the check for retired though why does still kickin return true, shouldnt myStatus make it be false since it's not retired?

Comment: oh, still kickin is put in as the value for isretired,  since it connects to myStatus. but still since it's not exactly retired why turn true?

Comment: @HectorAgosto  _Your_ code started with `status`  to `False` followed by an potentially endless `while` loop (only entered when `status == True`) that tested if `status == "retired"` but did nothing with the testresult - so _if_ `status` had been `True`: endless loop. I (maybe wrongly) deducted you want to differentiate between ppl that are 65 and still work (why not?) and ppl that are 65 and stopped working (`status` is "retired"). Discounts only go to ppl that are < 18 or >=65 and not working anymore. Hence the differentiation. Thats why `status` matters for getting discounts if > 65y

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PatrickArtner i was able to do it with the initial IF statement i was building the program upon. Thank you!!!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


def statusCheck(somage):
    if somage >= 65:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def ageCheck():
    while True:

        age = input("Enter Your Age: ")

        if age.isdigit() and int(age) > 0: 
            return int(age)

def discountCheck(someage, mystatus):
        if (someage >= 65 and mystatus == "isAble") or someage < 18: 
            print("You get 5% off")
        else:
            print("Age inacceptable")

def welcome():
    print()
    print("Welcome to Age Test")


welcome()

age = ageCheck()
statusCheck(age)

def ifstatus():
    if statusCheck(age) == True:
        status = "isAble"
        return str(status)

status =  ifstatus()

discountCheck(age, status)
```